# Unable to CREATE DATABASE via PyODBC connection

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` in `python 2.7` with `MS SQL Server 2008R`.

Here is my code for creating a database (the SQL code which works fine in SQL alone, but crash when executed in python)

```
SQL_command = """
                IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE [name] = 'NewDatabase')
                    DROP DATABASE NewDatabase
              """

conn.cursor.execute(SQL_command)

SQL_command = """
                CREATE DATABASE NewDatabase
                ON     
                (
                     NAME = 'NewDatabase_data'
                ,    FILENAME='D:\MSSQL\DATA\NewDatabase_data.mdf' 
                ,    SIZE = 4096KB 
                ,    FILEGROWTH = 4096KB 
                ) 
                LOG ON  
                (
                    NAME = 'NewDatabase_log'
                ,   FILENAME='D:\MSSQL\LOG\NewDatabase_log.ldf' 
                ,    SIZE = 4096KB 
                ,    FILEGROWTH = 10%
                ) 
                COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
              """

conn.cursor.execute(SQL_command)

SQL_command = """
                ALTER DATABASE 
                    NewDatabase
                SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
              """

conn.cursor.execute(SQL_command)
```

However, I've got following error message:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within
>   multi-statement transaction. (226) (SQLExecDirectW)')

May I know what is wrong with my code?

Many thanks.

====================================================================================

So, after taking the advice from @Matthias, I've executed `commit` after the `drop database`, then the error message became:

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver][SQL Server]CREATE FILE encountered operating system
>   error 123(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while
>   attempting to open or create the physical file
>   'D:\MSSQL\DATA\NewDatabase_data.mdf'. (5123)
>   (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be
>   created. Check related errors. (1802)")

Comment: Try to do a `COMMIT` after you execute the `DROP DATABASE` and `CREATE DATABASE` commands.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for your reply. I've tried your advice, still no good. But the error has changed, the new error message is posted, please have a look. Many thanks.

Comment: try: `autocommit = True` see `pyodbc.connect: (str, autocommit='False', ansi='False', timeout='0', **kwargs)`.

Comment: Just guessing: Looks like your program doesn't have write permission in this folder.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have permission to write in the folder.

Comment: @ChangeMyName Make sure the path exists and the *SQL Server service account* has permission to the folder. Your personal account permissions aren't relevant.

Comment: Hopefully this is still of some use to you, but as I'm working with PyODBC myself right now, I would recommend executing each statement individually instead of as a batch. The reason for this is that block comments in python, if properly indented, cannot ignore their leading whitespace. It's easier to relay the commands as a series. Where blocks are necessary, you can pass the block through a library like `textwrap` to get rid of the leading whitespace for each line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction" when using pyodbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006192/create-database-statement-not-allowed-within-multi-statement-transaction-when)