# "CREATE ... statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction" when using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm trying to create a SQL Server database using pyodbc.

```python
import pyodbc 
server = 'AMR112\NAMED1' 
database = 'msdb' 
username = '' 
password = 'mypassword' 
abcd='yes' 
ghi='False' 
#driver = '{/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so}' #for linux of windows 
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+??';PORT=1443;DATABASE??='+database+';UID='+??username+';PWD='+ password+';trusted_connection='+ abcd+'; autocommit='+ ghi) cursor = cnxn.cursor() 
cursor.execute("create database dbafgh") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
if row: 
    print row 
cursor.close()
```

It fails with this error

> CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

It fails because the `.execute` method starts a transaction and `CREATE DATABASE` cannot be run within a transaction.

So is there any other way to execute a `CREATE DATABASE` command using python?

Comment: Try [setting `autocommit = True`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1064149/61305).

Comment: I just tried. It doesnot work..

Comment: tried true as well. It fails

Comment: Then you're going to have to show your exact code. Related questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797319/sqlalchemy-mssql-create-database-statement-not-allowed-within-multi-statement-tr) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440711/unable-to-create-database-via-pyodbc-connection).

Comment: my code is as below:

Comment: import pyodbc
server = 'AMR112\NAMED1'
database = 'msdb'
username = ''
password = 'mypassword'
abcd='yes'
ghi='False'
#driver = '{/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so}'
#for linux of windows
driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';trusted_connection='+ abcd+'; autocommit='+ ghi)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create database dbafgh")
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row:
   print row
cursor.close()

Comment: Thanks Aaron Bertrand. after making autocommit =true. it started working. I was not setting it correctly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When establishing a connection, pyodbc defaults to `autocommit=False` in accordance with Python's DB-API spec. Therefore when the first SQL statement is executed, ODBC begins a database transaction that remains in effect until the Python code does a `.commit()` or a `.rollback()` on the connection.

SQL Server does not allow `CREATE DATABASE` to be executed within such a transaction, so we need to have the connection in `autocommit` mode before issuing such  statements. That can be accomplished when the connection is opened ...

```python
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)
```

... or by switching to `autocommit` mode if the connection is already established:

```python
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)  # autocommit=False by default
# ...
conn.autocommit = True
conn.execute("CREATE DATABASE MyNewDatabase")
```