# pyodbc error creating tables in SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
con = pyodbc.connect(connection_string) #connection_string already defined. con works
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE [schema].[TestTestTest](testcolumn1 int, testcolumn2 int)")
con.commit() #I've also tried cur.commit()
```

The error points to line 4 with the description:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]111212;Operation cannot be performed within a transaction. (111212) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any ideas? Can we not create tables with pyodbc?

Comment: Could be related to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006192/create-database-statement-not-allowed-within-multi-statement-transaction-when

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CREATE DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction" when using pyodbc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006192/create-database-statement-not-allowed-within-multi-statement-transaction-when)

Comment: Setting `con.autocommit = True` as the post that Gord and Wei linked to suggests did not help me when trying to create a table. I no longer got the error but no table was created. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

```
cur.execute('commit')
```

use the above comment, which will resolve your issue